# React hotreloading node_modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have the project and whenever I am adding package to node_modules
through yarn I need to kill my server. Is possible hot reloading,
to watch also the node_modules folder and automatically clean the error
of missing imports of libraries I am adding?

Comment: include `node_modules` as something to watch using nodemon.. but how often are you adding packages? it might not be worth it over just stopping/starting

Comment: In CRA, *node_modules* is specifically excluded from watch for performance reasons, also watching *node_modules* may not be possible in some scenarios due to a lack of system resources. - If you want to automatically add modules with webpack, you can use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/npm-install-webpack-plugin (though use at your own risk)